# Android 5.1 перехватывает события Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON

Tags: android, события, broadcast-receiver, android-broadcastreceiver

Перепробывал разные варианты кода перехвата событий 
`Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)`  
для кнопок проводной гарнитуры, 
например `case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:` 
по ссылке один из примеров от Google
[RandomMusicPlayer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/src/com/example/android/musicplayer)

на 4.4 все работает как ожидалось в логе приложения вижу что `onReceive` отрабатывает как надо, но **Android 5,1** перехватывает события стандартная регулировка громкости системы.

Comment: Каков приоритет у `Receiver`?

Comment: Приоритет выставил

                <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />

               по документации максимальное 1000 его тоже пробовал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недавно писал обработчик MEDIA_BUTTON, тоже столкнулся с проблемой, когда `receiver` срабатывал на 4.4 и не работал на 5.1, нашел такое решение :

```
public final class MediaButtonMonitorService extends Service {

    /**
     * Компонент обработки кнопок гарнитуры.
     */
    private ComponentName mMediaButtonReceiver = null;

    /**
     * Сессия.
     */
    private MediaSessionCompat mMediaSession = null;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Log.d("Create mediaButtonListener");

        // Создаем объекты для обработки кнопок гарнитуры

        mMediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(this, MediaButtonReceiver.class);

        mMediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "TAG", mMediaButtonReceiver, /* pendingIntent */ null);

        mMediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCustomAction(String action, Bundle extras) {
            super.onCustomAction(action, extras);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonEvent) {
            if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(mediaButtonEvent.getAction())) {
                final KeyEvent keyEvent = mediaButtonEvent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
                if (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN == keyEvent.getAction()) {
                    Log.v( "Media button down!");
                }
            } else {
                Log.v( "Unknown intent: " + mediaButtonEvent.getAction());
            }
            return true;
        }
        });

        mMediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS);

        mMediaSession.setActive(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.v("Start mediaButtonListener");

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.v("Finish mediaButtonListener");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Получилось так, что на 4.4 у меня срабатывал обычный `receiver`, а на 5.1 работал этот обработчик.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: По вашему примеру нашел на [github](https://github.com/pavelvpster/HeadsetLauncher) полноценный пример.